# How to make button in listview fit any screen

Tags: android, xml, listview, button

Am working on an xml code, but am having 2 issues, a. making the button fit to screen properly b.removing the space between the buttons. How do I make the button in a list-view fit to any screen, and also how do I remove the space between the buttons.Please edit my code when answering, thanks[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/content_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:context="org.cepfonline.lwponlineforum.activities.MainActivity"
   tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button04"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button05"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button06"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the gap or margin between the default android button come from the background image used in the button.

**First option** 
your can use the android button style like this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Second option is to use background color on each button. So the complete code is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button04"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Image before and after

[image]

Comment: cant I close the space without using the background colour trick

Comment: No, because I think it comes from the default background image. May be with transparent image borders

Comment: which default background image, am not using any, and if there is a default where did it come from and how can i remove it

Comment: I am not sure but you can check the Button view class in android source code